# Reading multiple parts of a file async using tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I got really stuck at this very simple problem in rust:

Ideally using a single core CPU, I want to be able to read a parts of the same file in a non blocking way:

```
struct PrefetchOp {
}

impl PrefetchOp {

  async fn start (currentData: [u8;8]) {
    let next = self.prefetch(); // this reads data from disk and puts it in memory
    self.perform_slow_step(currentData);

    let mut future
    for x in 0..100 {
      future = self.prefetch();
      self.perform_slow_step(next.await);
      next = future;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to write a prefetch which reads data in an async way such that hopefully it will be ready by the next slow step or that line will wait for it to be done.

Now, prefetch is reading parts of the same file and my plan was to:

- Implement a future that creates the file descriptor, performs a `poll_seek` and performs `poll_read`
- Or, create a file descriptor before the loop and have a future that does the `poll_seek` and the `poll_read`. Will I not have concurrency issues then?

How can I do this in the simplest most elegant way?

Comment: this is how tokio do it without using a stream of chunk, https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/src/tokio_fs/read.rs.html#48.

Comment: you could probably use https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio/doc/tokio/prelude/trait.AsyncRead.html

Comment: do both strategy avoid waiting to read?